# Looking for alternatives to Empathy for Ubuntu 12.04 and above

Tags: instant-messaging

I've been looking around at different messaging software however all the documents online are going back to 2009.

**Is the any other new alternatives to Empathy?**

Thanks

This is different and not a duplicate because I'm asking about **NEW** instant messaging **FOR 12.04** and above. Not oldies.

Comment: Well, I'll vote to re-open this, but I don't think there has been much change since that other question was asked.

Answer (score 1):

Pidgin is a good one, try it, it is nice ;)

One of Pidgins strongest selling points is its support for a multitude of various different IM protocols - a selection of which are: MSN, Yahoo, AIM, Gtalk and even IRC! Uniquely, with Pidgin you can log in to multiple accounts simultaneously. This means that you can be chatting with friends on AIM, flirting with contacts on Yahoo! - all whilst nattering away to your MSN buddies - all at the same time. Pidgin supports the usual IM features such as file transfer, customised status/nick names, away messages and typing notification. 'Simple' and 'Clean' are two words i would use to describe Pidgin's interface. from http://www.tuxmachines.org/node/47484